# Gradle - MultipleCompilationErrorsException on Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I try to create gradle project on Intellij, although I'm ensured that I chose JDK 8 but it gives me an error. I use windows 10 & unfortunately most of the questions have been asked concerning android on Stackoverflow. grateful for the help.

I mention error hereunder:

```
 Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
```

Comment: Add more information where you see this error and the IDE version you use. Also include a full error text.

Comment: I already mentioned IDE that is Intellij, also the error I've mentioned is all what  I get, I meant full error text, What more should I mention, I get this at the beginning

Comment: Attach a screenshot, the full output you get in **Build** tool window and idea.log file 
 (Help | Show Log in ... action)after this happens. As a possible workaround it may help to change the Gradle version in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Use Gradle from** or Gradle JDK for project - **Gradle JVM**.

Comment: Might be the same issue as in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245303 Do you have IDE installed on the C drive?

Comment: Many thanks Andrey, I will try it later because I already started my project on Maven

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error. If you check the whole exception (one level before that one - in the Build panel), maybe it will give you the correct exception. In my case, it was "General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60 in java.".
I have changed the Gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to 7.2v (distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip) and it worked fine.

Comment: This works and thanks. While I find my error is not due to the expiration of the gradle compiler but due to a sudden change. I feel that there is a chance that I encountered some network flow change for one of the real-time updating files in .gradle but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

in my case the problem was that i created a common android-library.gradle script and used this sintax,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
```

when tried to apply the script to other gradle scripts i got the same error
the solution was to replace with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```